# Can I speed up decodeAudioData sampling from Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web, decode

I'm using Web audio api decodeAudioData() method to decode audio files (45min duration, about 40MB, mp3 format) stored on my ubuntu web server. When user enter on some website page I need to preload Audio file, but it takes too long, about 1min 10s. Is it possible to do something to speed up this process? I'm getting arraybuffer through xmlhtttprequest and then decoding it, but it is very very slow.

**EDIT:**  I was tottaly wrong. After measurements I realised that problem is in downloading file. Processing is only 10 secs which is good.

Comment: there are 2 parts Downloading the File and Playing the file. Which part is taking more time?

Comment: I dont' know about downloading, server uses file from local machine, after xmlhttprequest, in php I call readfile($localpath) then return that arraybuffer to javascript where decoding is called

Comment: Can't you slice your file in multiple smaller ones ?

Comment: It needs to be played as one audio record on website, I have 27 GB material so that isn't easy

Comment: Your file is 40MB in size. Measure how much time it is taking in downloading. and then measure how much time it takes to decode. Depending which is more you should go for optimization.

Comment: Well you can always decode smaller chunks of audio, then concatenate whatever you are doing with the decoded data.

Comment: a general solution is streaming in which you dont download the entire file but parts of it and keep it playing. simultaneously downloading chunks in background

Comment: I realised that problem is in downloading, I was totally wrong, any solutions? Thank you avck